# How do I remove-items in a folder without the confirm box popping up?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, popupmenu, confirmation

I want to deleted all the files in the temp folder... any .zip files , .txt files and any folder files including whatever is inside each of those folders (everything). I thought this would be simple but so far my script keeps getting the confirmation pop-up asking if I want to delete all these child items. I tried using `-confirm:$false` but that doesn't seem to work. I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

```bash
$list = Get-ChildItem -directory "C:\temp\*" -Include * -Name 
get-childitem c:\temp -Include @(get-content $list) | Remove-Item -Force -whatif
```

I tried using the `-confirm:$false` argument as well as the `-force` with no luck.

Comment: In order to avoid a confirmation prompt when using `Remove-Item` to remove a _non-empty directory_, use `-Recurse`; add `-Force` to additionally ensure that removal succeeds if the directory happens to contain _hidden_ items. `-Confirm:$false` _in addition_ is only needed if the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable's value was changed from its default (`'High'`). See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want -path vs -directory.

```
#Looking for Temp under Windows:
$list = (Get-ChildItem -path "C:\*\Temp*\*.*").FullName | Remove-Item -Force

#Looking for Temp under Root:
$list = (Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Temp*\*.*").FullName | Remove-Item -Force
```

If your Temp dirs have subs you could also add the -recurse switch.

Comment: Note: you'll get errors if the Temp file is being used by some current process!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confirmation requests add the parameter `-confirm:$false`. If you want to include everything don't specify the parameter `-include *` - the default is to return everything, no need to slow down due to unecessary filters.

just do:

```
get-childitem -path C:\temp -directory | remove-item -force -confirm:$false -recurse
```

btw. u did specify the parameter `-directory`, currently only directories are returned by get-childitem, so files directly stored in C:\temp would remain.